# fuel injectors in a 2003 Cadillac Deville

Tags: smoke, fuel-injectors, cadillac, deville

What determines when your fuel injectors need cleaning? My car is emitting white smoke when pressing on the gas petal after stopping at a traffic light.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! White smoke is usually a sign of a coolant leak, though if it was light blue enough, it might be mistaken for white (having some slight amount of oil getting burned). If there was too much fueling going on, you'd be seeing black smoke. I'm not sure which engine you have in your Deville?

Comment: Rough running, lumpy idle are some of the signs of injector issues, but white smoke could just be condensation of water vapor, or as Paulster2 suggested...